# how to address the person who read the texts of digital audio guide in museum?

Tags: names

Some museum provides cellphone application with a digital audio guide, when we click a certain collection, there is introduction of that objects. How to address the person who read the text? He or she is not actually an interpreter since he or she just read out what is provided by the museum curator. Maybe a dubber?

Comment: I suspect you mean *describe* rather than *address*.

Comment: thank you. I misuse "address" as in "How should I address you", and thought "to address sb. " equals how to call/describe somebody doing a certain job/task/activity.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** a studio offering *[training for such artists](https://www.edgestudio.com/audio-tours-training)* refers to them thusly:

> One of the most overlooked yet fertile career tracks for **voice artists** is the audio tour.
>   …
>   **Audio tour voice over narrators** are specialists in vocal inflection, timing and pacing – and they are highly sought after by producers and directors.
>   …

---

**Original answer:**

The person reading the text, *while reading it*, would typically be called *the **narrator*** (this is [how Audible refer to them](http://www.audible.com/int/Featured_Narrators), for example).

Other, less specific terms include ***artist*** or ***performer***.

In general you can use a variety of terms for the person or profession. Someone who also or usually performs more serious “dramatic” recording work might be a ***voice actor***¹ or, in non-dramatic rôles, a ***voice-over artist***:

> From Oxford *Living* Dictionaries:
>
> > ***[voice actor](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/voice_actor)***
> >
> > > NOUN
> > >
> > > A person whose job is to provide the voices for characters in animated films, dubbed foreign language films, audio dramas, etc.
> > >       ***‘when I arrived in Hollywood in after drama school, I hoped to find work as a voice actor’***
>
> and
>
> > ***[voice-over](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/voice-over)***
> >
> > > NOUN
> > >       A piece of narration in a film or broadcast, not accompanied by an image of the speaker.
> > >       ***‘the budget is summarized in a voice-over at the end of the news’***
> > >       *[mass noun] **‘the coordination of live voice-over, music, and slides’***
> > >       *[as modifier] **‘voice-over dialogue’***
> > >
> > > VERB
> > >       [WITH OBJECT]
> > >       Narrate (spoken material) for a film or broadcast as a voice-over.
> > >       ***‘we had to voice-over some passages of dialogue’***
> > >       ***‘the commercials are voice-overed’***

¹ This is very likely *not* the answer you want unless that is their vocation, and they happen to be “performing” audio books as their regular job.

Comment: Oh do let us get into that"!  As one of those people (the guy who says "tonight at 9:00" on a large television outlet) I prefer *voice-over artist,* despite a certain chagrin regarding the "artist" part. An *actor* impersonates or interprets another, while a v-o person/artist/speaker delivers lines in what is often an uncharacterized, generally objective tone.  *("This comment was made possible by posters like you, and by...")*

Comment: Ah, I was trying to make that distinction but wanted to avoid any implied value judgement *on my part* (otherwise I'd have added another citation, but it was somewhat snobby in tone). Please feel free to edit, btw.

Comment: *Narrator* properly refers specifically to someone that tells a narrative (story).  *Reader* and *speaker* are more general terms that could be used.

Comment: In the context in question, I find the terms *artist* and *performer* inappropriate, since they suggest that the speaker is an attraction in their own right, not merely conveying information *about* the main attraction (i.e. the museum exhibits).

Comment: How so? If I get a portrait painted, I'm hardly going to avoid referring to the painter as *artist* in case it goes to their head ...

Comment: @DavidEger you'll find *narrator* - story *teller* - is not the same as *author*, though. Example definition: *[the character who tells you what is happening in a book or film (Cambridge)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/narrator)*. Narrator is, quite literally, what they are.

Comment: @DavidEger ... and if a museum staff have produced a script, then the person reading it (especially if hired to do so), is most definitely a *performer*.

Comment: ... think of the exhibits as *characters* (or maybe *“props”*) and their (possibly overlapping or shared) history as *the story*.

Answer (score 1):

Such a museum guide, virtual or not, is normally referred to as a *[docent](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/docent?s=ts)*:

> **docent**, *n.*: a person who is a knowledgeable guide, especially one who conducts visitors through a museum and delivers a commentary on
>   the exhibitions.

Comment: OP asked specifically what to call the person reading the text - who may have *no* knowledge, if they’re simply hired to read the script.

Answer (score 0):

In the specific case of a museum audio guide voice-over artist seems a bit grandiose. Even narrator sounds a bit pompous. I have heard just the words "voice-over", as in 'the voice-over says it dates from the 18th century'.

Comment: OP asked for a name for the person *doing* the “voice-over”, ... i.e. the voice-over *artist*.